# OncePerRequestFilter is not called when user tries to log in with wrong credentials

Tags: spring, spring-boot, filter

in my App I have the following OncePerRequestFilter but its not called when user tries to login with wrong credentials.
With correct credentials the filter is called.

Does someone know why it's not called?

```
@Component
public class LoginFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, 
HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {


    if (httpServletRequest.getRequestURI().contains("/sign-in")) {
        String username = httpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal().getName();
        //do things here
    } else {
        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hi midi, please try @Order annotation for your filter and give it Integer.MIN_VALUE; then your filter is coming into play at the first place. For further details about Order annotation https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html.

Comment: Thx @nurisezgin, this did the trick!